# HiveQL - How to tackle with elements not appearing in dictionary

Tags: hiveql

The thing is: I've got this lookup table which I use as a dictionary to create a new column that 'translates' the meaning of a certain column of codes.

Let's say:

Table1:

```
ID    Code
01    A
02    B
03    C
```

Lookup_table (dictionary):

```
Code   Meaning
A      Alice
B      Bob
C      Charlie
```

I can easily make a JOIN to create a new table (Table2) with the new column 'Meaning' added to it:

Table2:

```
CREATE TABLE Table2 AS SELECT T1.ID, T1.Code, LKP.Meaning
FROM Table1 AS T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Lookup_table AS LKP
ON (T1.Code = LKP.Code);
```

But: What to do if a new Code appears in Table1 (e.g. ("04", "D") ) and there is no translation for it in Lookup_table? (given you want to avoid a NULL as an answer) Is there a way to obtain something like 'others' in Meaning to answer to this situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `COALESCE()` in order to achieve that. `COALESCE()` takes two arguments, while selecting the first argument that is not `NULL`.

You can modify your query as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Table2 AS 
SELECT 
T1.ID AS ID, 
T1.Code AS Code, 
COALESCE(LKP.Meaning,'others') AS Meaning
FROM Table1 AS T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Lookup_table AS LKP
ON (T1.Code = LKP.Code);
```

In your case this would mean to put `LKP.Meaning` as first parameter. If this value is `NULL`, it will use `'others'` as displayed.

See also the [Hive Documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF).

Comment: Thanks! It works fine. I was using a workaround with auxiliary tables, but yours is a much more elegant solution. Good!